# git add -a vs -A (lowercase vs uppercase)

Tags: git

Today I feel like a child who has discovered that what he has always done is actually wrong :-)

I have always lowercased the --all parameter with `-a` in my git add command until today. In a tutorial on Github Action I see that the colleague writes `git add -A`.  Which is apparently correct according to the Git documentation.(https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

The following parameter notations for (`--all`) possibilities can be used according to git:

```
--all
-A
-no-ignore-removal
```

**Question:** Is `-a` only tolerated by git or is there another meaning ... or should it even be avoided completely?

Comment: I would tend toward avoiding it; however `git add` treats it, it seems to be undocumented. At least in Git 2.32.0, `git add -a` produces an "unknown switch `a'" error.

Comment: Note that `--a` is a valid abbreviation for `--all`, though, as no other long option starts with `a`.

Comment: @chepner Good to know! From today only `git add -A`. Thank you!